# Failed to install node-sass trough npm

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, package.json, node-sass

For a project I use gulp and various dependencies. A few months ago I was able to work with it without any complications. After a reinstallation of my OS I now get the error that **node-sass cannot be installed**. Node, NPM and NPX are on the latest version

Tried to fix that with `npm install`, `npm rebuild`
, `npm rebuild node-sass` and deleting package-lock.json/node_modules folder and reinstalled it. Still getting the same Error:

```
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/skayan/Sites/gulpino/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/Cellar/node/16.8.0/bin/node /Users/skayan/Sites/gulpino/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/skayan/.node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node -I/Users/skayan/.node-gyp/16.8.0/src -I/Users/skayan/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/skayan/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/skayan/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/skayan/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/skayan/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
....
```

In the terminal, it always stops here:

```
⸨##################⸩ ⠹ reify:node-sass: timing reify:audit Completed in 1139ms
```

The status bar says this:

```
clang <- npm install gulp-sass
```

Is it something to do with a version conflict or how do I get this bug fixed?

Comment: What version of `node` do you have and what `node-sass` version are you trying to install ? Have you tried deleting `node_modules` folder and install again ?

Comment: node is on v16.8.0 and node-sass is not listed in my dependencied so I assume that npm-install takes the latest version. gulp-sass 4.1.0 is listed on my dependencies list.

Yes, like i wrote above i already tried to delete and install it again.

But if delete "gulp-sass": "4.1.0" from my dependencies list npm install